# UIDatePicker return value data type question

Tags: iphone, delegates, types, uiactionsheet

I want to pass back data from a UIDatePicker that is setup like this:

```
UIDatePicker *pickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
pickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer;
```

The picker mode is set to be the count down timer. What type of data type do I need to pass back to the delegate?

I was thinking it would be something like `pickerView.value` But I am not seeing it. Do I need to get the `pickerView.date` and cast it as an NSNumber or something?

I just want to setup a timer based on the value I am getting back from the UIDatePicker...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pickerView.countDownDuration`, which returns an NSTimeInterval (a double).